# rename multiple files selected by criteria in windows via comand line .rev1

Tags: vbscript

Greatings,

I am trying to rename files from one director, files that have digits format, following this pathern xx.pdf, xx,1.pdf, x.pdf, x,1.pdf to become >>> xxx.pdf or xxx,1 (where is the comma)
(ex. 12.pdf, 15.pdf, 01,1.pdf, 14,2.pdf etc) >>> (012.pdf, 015.pdf, 001,1.pdf, 014,2.pdf). I like to do this from command line, in Windows 10.

Sugestion, how can I do this?

Comment: You can post your code draft and we will be happy to help you!

Comment: Hi Mihai, I didn't had time to come in this place. But thanks that you offer your help. See you (maybe) on diffrent question. kr,

Answer (score 0):

This is what is working for me (it is not cover character like ²³ or something strange) It is following this pathern: 1.pdf will become 001.pdf, 01,2.pdf will become 001,2.pdf etc. (this is what I was looking for). But today, I had time to play around.

```
Dim sFolder
Dim intLength

sFolder = "C:\pdf_to_be_order"

Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

For Each oFile In oFSO.GetFolder(sFolder).Files
  If UCase(oFSO.GetExtensionName(oFile.Name)) = "PDF" Then
    If IsNumeric(oFSO.GetBaseName(oFile)) Then 
        if InStrRev(oFSO.GetBaseName(oFile), ",") > 0 then 
            intLength = Len(oFSO.GetBaseName(oFile))
            Select Case intLength           
            Case 3
                oFSO.MoveFile oFile.path, sFolder & "\" & "00" & oFile.name
            Case 4
                oFSO.MoveFile oFile.path, sFolder & "\" & "0" & oFile.name
            Case Else
            End Select

        else
            intLength = Len(oFSO.GetBaseName(oFile))
            Select Case intLength           
            Case 1
                oFSO.MoveFile oFile.path, sFolder & "\" & "00" & oFile.name
            Case 2
                oFSO.MoveFile oFile.path, sFolder & "\" & "0" & oFile.name
            Case Else
            End Select

        end if

    end if


  End if
Next
```